# Como gravar adicionar e gravar item no ficheiro em angular?

Tags: angularjs

Eu estou tentando usar esse [exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/ckosloski/NfPcH/19061/):

Mas nao estou conseguindo que grave. Ou seja, insiro dados e salvo, mas quando atualizo a pagina desfaz as alterações, e no ficheiro nao adiciona novos itens.

Todos os exemplos que testei acontece o mesmo. Julgo por falta algo que autorize a gravação de dados no ficheiro, mas nãosei o que é?

Não sei muito sobre `Angular`.

Comment: Poste o que você tentou até agora (código)

Comment: Será que o problema não é no back-end (`$http.post('/saveUser', user)`)?